# Debug a test that only fails on TeamCity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, integration-testing

I have several random failing integration tests running on TeamCity.  These tests do not fail locally.  I've even tried making my local site hit the dev database.

Does anyone have experience debugging weird issues like this?

We are using MVC 4 (C#) and MSBuild.

Comment: Please, be more specific

Comment: what are the type of failure messages from build message?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was with a load balanced solution.  The two web servers were out of sync causing odd timing issues.

One web server would save it, then another would pick it up to the processing and the time was in the past.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you don't give lots of information, but the straightforward anser to the question "how to debug this" would be to put a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` statement right before the failing test. Then you'll have the chance to attach the debugger, and off you go.